# pandas: type conversion returning incorrect value

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, casting, floating-point

I have a DataFrame which looks like this:

```
Values  Total
Values       
cbase    2019
```

Here's a better look at the value:

```
>>> df.values
[[ 2019.]]

>>> df.dtypes
Values
Total     float64
dtype: object
```

Now I would like to ensure that the value is an integer (no decimal), so I do:

```
df.astype(int64)

Values  Total
Values       
cbase    2018
```

The value has changed from 2019 to 2018. I'm curious; what is going on?

Comment: Please post data and reproducible code, also what does `df.values[0]` show?

Comment: Cannot post the data, it's insanely massive. it shows df.values[0]
[ 2019.]

Comment: post enough data and code that reproduces this error, otherwise this becomes a guessing game

Comment: I understand Ed but getting the data would be difficult to extract for me. Still a newb you see.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think this is a rounding-for-representation thing; your value in the Pandas object is actually very slightly under 2019. For example:

```
>>> v = np.nextafter(2019, 0)
>>> v
2018.9999999999998
```

If you put this value `v` in a DataFrame; it rounds to 2019 for the representation:

```
>>> df = pd.DataFrame([v])
>>> df
      0
0  2019
```

However, casting `df` to an integer just drops the fractional part of the number so you get 2018:

```
>>> df.astype(int)
      0
0  2018
```

Comment: This seems like the cause. So the solution would be to round the value? to get 2019

Comment: Yes you could round instead to get to the closest integer (and then cast to float) - it depends on what your data represents and whether it is of any significance that this value is actually slightly less than 2019.

Comment: (I meant *and then cast to int*)