# Extract only ids from json files and read them into a CSV file

Tags: python, json, pandas

I have a folder including multiple JSON files. Here is a sample JSON file (all JSON files have the same structure):

```
{
   "url": "http://www.lulu.com/shop/alfred-d-byrd/in-the-fire-of-dawn/paperback/product-1108729.html", 
   "label": "true", 
   "body": "SOME TEXT HERE",
   "ids": [
       "360175950098468864",  
       "394147879201148929"
   ]
}
```

**I'd like to extract only `ids` and write them into a CSV file.** Here is my code:

```
import pandas as pd
import os
from os import path
import glob
import csv
import json

input_path = "TEST/True_JSON"
for file in glob.glob(os.path.join(input_path,'*.json')):
    with open(file,'rt') as json_file:
        json_data = pd.read_json(json_file)  #reading json into a pandas dataframe
        ids = json_data[['ids']] #select only "response_tweet_ids" 
        ids.to_csv('TEST/ids.csv',encoding='utf-8', header=False, index=False)

print(ids)
```

Problem: the above code writes some ids into a CSV file. However, it doesn't return all ids. Also, there are some ids in the output CSV file (ids.csv) that didn't exist in any of my JSON files!

Comment: you overwrite the output file `TEST/ids.csv` and print only last `ids`  does it make sense?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

one other way is create common list for all ids in the folder and write it to the output file only once, here example:

```
input_path = "TEST/True_JSON"
ids = []
for file in glob.glob(os.path.join(input_path,'*.json')):
    with open(file,'rt') as json_file:
        json_data = pd.read_json(json_file)  #reading json into a pandas dataframe
        ids.extend(json_data['ids'].to_list()) #select only "response_tweet_ids" 

pd.DataFrame(
    ids, colums=('ids', )
).to_csv('TEST/ids.csv',encoding='utf-8', header=False, index=False)

print(ids)
```

Please read the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68352361/8060120) by @lemonhead to get more details.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Now I get this error: `'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'to_list'`

Comment: @Brown Bear Nice answer, just for completeness, you may want to also include something about the precision bug when reading in ids as int64's mentioned in my answer, which is probably the cause of the ```ids in the output CSV file (ids.csv) that didn't exist in any of my JSON files!``` problem

Comment: @lemonhead updated the answer with link to your (DRY) =)

Answer (score 1):

I think you have two main issues here:

1. pandas seems to read in ids off-by-1 in some cases, probably due to internally reading in as a float and then converting to an int64 and flooring.  See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33439617/pandas-type-conversion-returning-incorrect-value) for a similar issue encountered

To see this:

```
> x = '''
{
   "url": "http://www.lulu.com/shop/alfred-d-byrd/in-the-fire-of-dawn/paperback/product-1108729.html", 
   "label": "true", 
   "body": "SOME TEXT HERE",
   "ids": [
       "360175950098468864",  
       "394147879201148929"
   ]
}
'''
> print(pd.read_json(io.StringIO(x)))

# outputs: 
                                                 url label            body                 ids
0  http://www.lulu.com/shop/alfred-d-byrd/in-the-...  true  SOME TEXT HERE  360175950098468864
1  http://www.lulu.com/shop/alfred-d-byrd/in-the-...  true  SOME TEXT HERE  394147879201148928
```

Note the off by one error with `394147879201148929`! AFAIK, one quick way to obviate this in your case is just to tell `pandas` to read everything in as a string, e.g.

```
pd.read_json(json_file, dtype='string')
```

2. You are looping through your json files and writing each one to the same csv file.  However, [by default](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html#pandas-dataframe-to-csv), pandas is opening the file in 'w' mode, which will overwrite any previous data in the file.  If you open in append mode ('a') instead, that should do what you intended

```
ids.to_csv('TEST/ids.csv',encoding='utf-8', header=False, index=False, mode='a')
```

In context:

```
for file in glob.glob(os.path.join(input_path,'*.json')):
    with open(file,'rt') as json_file:
        json_data = pd.read_json(json_file, dtype='string')  #reading json into a pandas dataframe
        ids = json_data[['ids']] #select only "response_tweet_ids" 
        ids.to_csv('TEST/ids.csv',encoding='utf-8', header=False, index=False, mode='a')
```

Overall though, unless you are getting something else from `pandas` here, why not just use raw `json` and `csv` libraries? The following would be do the same without the `pandas` dependency:

```
import os
from os import path
import glob
import csv
import json

input_path = "TEST/True_JSON"
all_ids = []
for file in glob.glob(os.path.join(input_path,'*.json')):
    with open(file,'rt') as json_file:
        json_data = json.load(json_file)
        ids = json_data['ids']
        all_ids.extend(ids)

print(all_ids)

# write all ids to a csv file
# you could also remove duplicates or other post-processing at this point
with open('TEST/ids.csv', mode='wt', newline='') as fobj:
    writer = csv.writer(fobj)
    for row in all_ids:
        writer.writerow([row])
```

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer. Sorry, I already marked the response by @Brown Bear as the correct answer. But, I really appreciate you for mentioning useful points, especially `your point number 1` (ids off-by-1)

Answer (score 0):

By default, `dataframe.to_csv()` overwrites the file. So each time through the loop you replace the file with the IDs from that input file, and the final result is the IDs from the last file.

Use the `mode='a'` argument to append to the CSV file instead of overwriting.

```
ids.to_csv(
    'TEST/ids.csv', encoding='utf-8', header=False, index=False,
    mode='a'
)
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I tried `mode='a'`, but I get the same result yet :|